# extract week, month from DD-MON-YYYY hh.mm.ss AM/PM [Oracle Date] in Pandas Python

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am trying to Read a CSV File in Python - Pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
```

`import datetime as dt`

then i need to extract week month for further processing

```
df = pd.read_csv('C:\Python\dm.csv',low_memory=False)
df["SUBMITDATE"]=pd.to_datetime(df["SUBMITDATE"],format = '%d-%b-%y %I.%M.%S.%f %p')
df['Month']=df['SUBMITDATE'].dt.month
print df['Month']
```

> CSV Data File:

```
SUBMITDATE
15-MAR-16 10.11.01.000000000 PM,
15-MAR-16 10.11.01.000000000 PM,
15-MAR-16 10.11.01.000000000 PM,
```

> Output

```
15-MAR-16 10.11.01.000000000 PM   NaN 
15-MAR-16 10.11.01.000000000 PM   NaN
15-MAR-16 10.11.01.000000000 PM   NaN  
Name: Month, dtype: float64
```

Can i have a generic way to read any date format ?

Comment: For me your solution works nice, I think always need `format`, because a bit not standard format of datetime.

Comment: But i am not getting Month information extracted from the date?

Comment: am a bit confused with output of month, what is `print df[['SUBMITDATE','Month']]` ? - Please add it to question.

Comment: I am sorry i didnt get what you mean, Using df['Month']=df['SUBMITDATE'].dt.month     i am extracting month using datetime package and storing in df['Month']

Comment: So is imposible instead `print df['Month']` use `print df[['SUBMITDATE','Month']]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse dates with python functions like this (change to your date format accordingly):

```
def parse_datetime(x):
    '''
    Parses datetime with timezone formatted as:
        `[day/month/year:hour:minute:second zone]`

    Example:
        `>>> parse_datetime('13/Nov/2015:11:45:42 +0000')`
        `datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 3, 11, 45, 4, tzinfo=<UTC>)`

    Due to problems parsing the timezone (`%z`) with `datetime.strptime`, the 
    timezone will be obtained using the `pytz` library.
    '''    
    time = dt.datetime.strptime(x[1:-7], '%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S')
    dt_tz = int(x[-6:-3])*60+int(x[-3:-1])    
    return time.replace(tzinfo=pytz.FixedOffset(dt_tz))
```

and then in pandas:

```
...
pd.read_csv(
    file,
    sep=sep, 
    names=columns, 
    engine='python', 
    na_values='-',
    converters={
        'time': parse_datetime,
        ...
    })
...
```

create different converters for different datetime parts you need.